# In Asp.net Mvc Razor Syntax where is head tag define?

Tags: html, asp.net

Can any one tell me that In Asp.net Mvc Razor Syntax where is head tag define?

Comment: Wherever you want to put it.  HTML has nothing to do with Razor.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Head** tag same as **Html**

You can create Layout like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Project </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Your Content<p/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way it's defined in ordinary HTML. You could, for example, create a Layout page and create your head section there.